# Adding the tag to the title. Yes or no?

Tags: discussion, questions, tags

See [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11266/opengl-changing-player-color-without-multiple-player-bitmaps) as an example.

The user added OpenGL to the title, and tagged the question OpenGL. What do you think about the "tag" being in the title?

I know that over at gaming SE, you shouldn't add the tag into the title. Eg. `Starcraft2: How can I remember to build Supply Depots all game?` is bad, it should simply be: `How can I remember to build Supply Depots all game?`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Personally I hate this. If it's important, work the tag into the question grammatically, e.g. "How do I color my model in OpenGL?", "How do I change the color of a texture in Cocos2d?". If you're just going to slam ungrammatical tags on it, well, we have tags for that.

Comment: Aye for this practice. This is how the rest of the Stack Exchange Network operates as well - if you're going to include the tag in the title, do it organically. We already automatically append the most popular tag of a question into the page title if the title doesn't already contain it - prefacing a question with the tag is either redundant to this or makes it look extremely awkward.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to keep an eye on titles like these and edit them if necessary.

Comment: @bumm correct, this is my guidance -- if the tag works "naturally" in the title, use it there. If it does not, then the most popular tag is added to the HTML `<title>` on the page anyway, so you're covered in either case.